# Null Object Reference after creating the Object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have one MXML File as

```
<objecthandles:ObjectHandles xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  backgroundAlpha="1"                            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
allowRotate="true" minHeight="25" minWidth="60" height="100" width="200">

<s:BorderContainer  id="borderCon" width="100%" height="100%" minHeight="25" minWidth="60" 
                        backgroundAlpha="0" borderVisible="false" borderAlpha="0">
         <s:HGroup id="hgText" width="100%" height="100%" gap="0" >
            <mx:TextArea id="txtAdd" width="100%" height="100%" color="black" 
                         minHeight="25" minWidth="60" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" focusOut="txtAddKeyUpHandler(event)"  
                         keyUp="txtAddMirrorKeyUpHandler(event)"
                         creationComplete="onTextCreationComplete()" />
        </s:HGroup>
</s:BorderContainer>

</objecthandles:ObjectHandles>
```

When ever i create the object of the Fileas

var txtElement:TextElement = new TextElement();
txtElement.txtAdd.text = "Hello";

Then it showing the null object reference that
**txtElement.txtAdd seems to be null**

Need Perfect Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Flex component lifecycle subcomponents will not be created until the parent component is added to the displaylist. Only when the component is added to the displaylist **and** fully built, will you be able to access its subcomponents. When the component is completely ready for usage, it will dispatch a `FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` event.

So do something like this:

```
var txtElement:TextElement = new TextElement();
txtElement.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, initTxtElement);
addElement(txtElement);

private function initTxtElement(event:FlexEvent):void {
    txtElement.txtAdd.text = "Hello";
}
```

Or better yet, since it's a custom component: expose the 'text' property as a property of 'TextElement' and handle the deferred setting of the property internally, so that you can write: `txtElement.text = "hello"`.

Comment: Ya what You r saying is Correct. I accept this. some time it also shows null after creationComple. I might be posting after some time Thank U For Your Kind Answer

Comment: @Sudharsanan That's possible: if you work with states, not all subcomponents are immediately created.